# Hide default text for android switch Button

Tags: android, button, switch-statement

In my Android application I have used a Switch Button. Is there anyway to hide text of switch button? For API level 21 there is an option to hide (android:showText), but I need to run it on lower level devices.

Here is my xml file:

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/offbuttonbg"
        android:textAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switchselector" />
```

Comment: set empty string on textOff, textOn...,maybe...the simplest solution....

Comment: I agree, see an example answer below.

Comment: Yes i got it, very silly question, anyway thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For lower version, to hide the text use

```
 <Switch
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            android:background="@drawable/offbuttonbg"
            android:textAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
            android:thumb="@drawable/switchselector" />
```

Comment: what is the problem with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options one via code another via XML.

Via **Code:**

```
yourSwitch.setTextOff("textWhenOff") //Sets the text when the component is not in checked state.

yourSwitch.setTextOn("textWhenOn") //Sets the text when the component is not in checked state.
```

**XML**

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textOff="The text for the component when it's not checked."
        android:textOn="The text for the component when it's checked." 
        android:background="@drawable/offbuttonbg"
        android:textAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switchselector" />
```

Always refer to the [Switch Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) if you need more info.

Comment: user wants to hide the text

Comment: I agree that is why the solution of setting a textOff and textOn will work for this case, also looking at yours you are suggesting the same, just that only for XML, I gave both forms in code and XML,

No reason to down vote here.